# variable size text in android

Tags: android

Friends,I am trying to set a text of variable size in my app, but I am not getting the desired result.

```
msgInside=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
msgInside.setTextSize(30);
msgInside.setText("BIG MESSAGE");
msgInside.setTextSize(20);
msgInside.setText("SMALL MESSAGE");
```

I can only see the `SMALL MESSAGE`, I need to see both the messages

Comment: you can not set more than one message at the same time in textview. As "SMALL MESSAGE" is the last message u set so its not showing "BIG MESSAGE"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use spannable String for this purpose. Just try this,

```
        TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        Spannable span = new SpannableString("Hi this is Android");
        span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f), 0  , 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        text.setTextSize(20);
        text.setText(span);
```

[image]

Comment: you need to understand spannable. You have to know the start and end index of the text for which you need to set the size different. And using span you can set multiple font size to a single textView.

Answer (score 1):

use different textview for both text size message... its overright size of text if you use same textview for both message...

```
msgInside=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
msgInside.setTextSize(30);
msgInside.setText("BIG MESSAGE");
msgInside3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
msgInside3.setTextSize(20);
msgInside3.setText("SMALL MESSAGE");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same `textview` for your both texts. the second text will overwrite your first one.

For your desired result either use seperate texviews or use [Spannable String](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) to get seperate fonts, sizes etc.. in a single textview. [This](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring) is a nice tutorial for Spannable String

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can't use it double at a time, if u r ineterested in it then make a Reference object of that text view, i think u vl get something different and good.